# JBPM2 external dependencies versions not resolved properly in SBT

Tags: sbt, drools, jbpm

I'm trying to use jbpm2 6.0.0.Final in my sbt-based project.

Some problems occure with external dependencies. Artifact version is written using pom's variable reference. 
I can add those missing dependencies by hand and it will fix the matter but I still need to guest what versions are needed.

Any idea what is the best solution to this problem?

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler#ecj;${version.org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler}: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Comment: Show us your `build.sbt` and/or other sbt configuration files

Answer (score 0):

In jBPM we use the jbpm-bom to define all the version, look at here, it might help: https://github.com/droolsjbpm/droolsjbpm-build-bootstrap

Comment: I've tried to add the `bom` dependencies but it did not help. I think SBT does not honor settings from pom artifacts.